# GeoLiteCity binary database file size

Tags: geolocation

I've been using the GeoLiteCity binary database file for a while now and every couple months I upgrade to the latest version.

The database file I'm currently using is around 27MB.  Today I went to download the latest version and noticed that it is only around 15MB.  I'm wondering what could have changed to cause the file size to reduced by almost 50%.  Any ideas?  From what I can tell it still looks to provide the same level of coverage and accuracy as the prior versions.